# subtract two columns in a data frame if they have the same ending in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If my data looks like this

```
Index    Country    ted_Val1  sam_Val1 ... ted_Val10 sam_Val10
1        Australia  1     3    ... 20 5
2        Bambua     12    33   ... 15 56
3        Tambua     14    34   ... 10 58

df = pd.DataFrame([["Australia", 1, 3, 20, 5],
                   ["Bambua", 12, 33, 15, 56],
                   ["Tambua", 14, 34, 10, 58]
                  ], columns=["Country", "ted_Val1", "sam_Val1", "ted_Val10", "sam_Val10"]
                 )
```

I'd like to subtract all 'val_' columns from all 'ted_' values using a list, creating a new column starting with 'dif_' such that:

```
Index    Country    ted_Val1  sam_Val1 diff_Val1 ... ted_Val10 sam_Val10 diff_val10
1        Australia  1     3    -2 ... 20 5 -15
2        Bambua     12    33   12 ... 15 56 -41
3        Tambua     14    34   14... 10 58 -48
```

so far I've got:

```
calc_vars = ['ted_Val1',
'sam_Val1',
'ted_Val10',
'sam_Val10']
 
 for i in calc_vars:
     df_diff['dif_' + str(i)] = df.['ted_' + str(i)] - df.['sam_' + str(i)]
```

but I'm getting errors, not sure where to go from here. As a warning this is dummy data and there can be several underscores in the names

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use `filter` to choose the columns for subtraction (assuming your columns are properly sorted like your sample):

```
print (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.filter(like="ted").to_numpy()-df.filter(like="sam").to_numpy(),
                                   columns=["diff"+i.split("_")[-1] for i in df.columns if "ted_Val" in i])],1))

     Country  ted_Val1  sam_Val1  ted_Val10  sam_Val10  diff1  diff10
0  Australia         1         3         20          5     -2      15
1     Bambua        12        33         15         56    -21     -41
2     Tambua        14        34         10         58    -20     -48
```

Comment: the values are not in the order like my sample :-/, ideally I wouldn't use 'window' references

Comment: Then sort the columns first by `df.reindex(sorted(df.columns),axis=1)`.

Comment: this would just group all the ted and sam columns right? not put it into the desired order

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you do `df.filter`, it returns a sorted view of `ted` and `sam` separately, which you can compare the two matrix of values directly since both are sorted.

Comment: I see, so I used dummy data here, and the real column names can have several underscores in it, this is messing up my trials as we are splitting on that. There is no way to do it using the list? or for example I have a list of the common endings (no 'on_' 'off_')

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
calc_vars = ['ted_Val1', 'sam_Val1', 'ted_Val10', 'sam_Val10']

# extract even & odd values from calc_vars
# ['ted_Val1', 'ted_Val10'], ['sam_Val1', 'sam_Val10']

for ted, sam in zip(calc_vars[::2], calc_vars[1::2]):
    df['diff_' + ted.split("_")[-1]] = df[ted] - df[sam]
```

---

**Edit**: if columns are not sorted,

```
ted_cols = sorted(df.filter(regex="ted_Val\d+"), key=lambda x : x.split("_")[-1])
sam_cols = sorted(df.filter(regex="sam_Val\d+"), key=lambda x : x.split("_")[-1])

for ted, sam in zip(ted_cols, sam_cols):
    df['diff_' + ted.split("_")[-1]] = df[ted] - df[sam]
```

---

```
     Country  ted_Val1  sam_Val1  ted_Val10  sam_Val10  diff_Val1  diff_Val10
0  Australia         1         3         20          5         -2          15
1     Bambua        12        33         15         56        -21         -41
2     Tambua        14        34         10         58        -20         -48
```

Comment: does this depend on the values being in the proper order?

Comment: If you are asking about values in ``calc_vars``, yes it matters.

Comment: sorry, they are not sorted or might not be sorted like that, is it possible to do it otherwise?

Comment: @Jogianni updated answer will work agnostic of column order.

Comment: thank you, I am struggling with the split thing, since my real columns have multiple underscores in them and frequently the same final ending before the last underscore. This has lead to many fields named the same. Is there anyway to do it without the split?

Comment: Yes there are multiple ways.. but that's not the scope of this question, I would recommend asking a new question to get a better answer.